# Webbrowser: catch Ajax loading progress element

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, ajax, browser

I'm using Webbrowser to automate some webpage. To indicate whether ajax finished its job I have to check for loading indicator that is shown while ajax loading is in progress. But I cannot catch this image with Firebug as loading takes 1-2 seconds. How to catch it and see its name to identify it in my code?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You question is a little unclear and I'm not sure exactly what you mean but One possible solution could be to go into HTML tab in firebug and right click on  tag and select "Break on child addition or removal" and then step through until you find what your looking for.

But without a clear question it is hard to say.

Comment: He needs to get some identifying attribute for this ajax loading image, but since it comes and goes so fast he doesn't have time to see it. I think your answer will help him.

Comment: you could also clear the cache and then find the loading image in firebug NET tab. then search your code for the file name.